# Objective-C, NSTask won't touch files

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager, nstask

I have the following code (below) in my app, which simply tries to use NSTask to touch one file with the directory time/date stamp. It works just fine in an app which only accesses one directory all the time, however, it doesn't with another that frequently changes directories to access some of it's data. When I check the currentfile and currentpath they both show the correct paths. I've expired every possibility I can think of; any help would be great appreciated — thank you.

```
- (void)someMethod:(NSString *)currentfile {

    NSFileManager *filemanager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

    if ([filemanager changeCurrentDirectoryPath: @"/"] == NO)
    NSLog (@"Cannot change directory.\n");

    NSString *currentpath = [filemanager currentDirectoryPath];
    NSLog (@"Current directory is %@", currentpath);

    [filemanager release];

    NSArray*arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-r",currentpath,currentfile,nil];

    [self touchFiles:arguments];

    return;
}

- (void)touchFiles:(NSArray *)arguments {

    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

    [task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/touch"];

    [task setArguments:arguments];

    [task launch];

    [task release];

    return;
}
```

Comment: Note that current directory is per process and not per thread. So if you have concurrent threads you could end up with a race condition as changing and getting the current directory is not done atomically.

Comment: @MattiasWadman, i think it might be a race condition, since everything i've tried ends in the same result. how exactly does one deal with such things effectively?

Comment: Is this the actual code? do you always change directory to "/" (root)? what is the reason you want to touch both / and the file? if you use change dir stuff only to get directory path etc i think you should use the `NSString` path methods. If not you could use some locking mechanism like `@synchronize` to make the code atomic.

Comment: that's way over my head. i change to different directory's using the above method (NSFileManager), i simply would like it to run the equivalent command `# touch -r file1 file2` that's it. It works fine on any other apps that don't traverse all over the place; so maybe it's losing it's way or something. thanks

Comment: Ok but if you have the absolute paths to both file1 and file2 you dont need to change the working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change a file's modification time without using `NSTask`.  Use `-[NSURL setResourceValue:forKey:error:]` with the key `NSURLContentModificationDateKey`.

As to why your use of `NSTask` and `touch` is failing, perhaps you don't have permissions to modify the file's modification time. Check the console log to see if any error was reported from `touch` or redirect the task's standard error output to someplace else and check that.

Comment: no errors even when re-directing the output. I think it's a matter of the threads not being in sync, although it's tough to tell; thanks for the response though, i'll look into your suggestion. I've tried NSFileManager also with the same exact result. :-/

Comment: What threads? There's no reason to imagine this is a multi-threading issue.

Comment: I don't know; someone mentioned it in the other comments. What else could it be?

Comment: He was suggesting that, if your `-someMethod:` is invoked simultaneously with some other method running in another thread that's also using `-[NSFileManager changeCurrentDirectoryPath:]`, then the current directory may get switched away from `/` between when you set it and when you query it. By the way, that's sort of insane. Why are you doing that? If you want the `NSTask` to have a particular working directory, then set its working directory, not the current process's. Even better, use absolute paths and don't rely on the working directory at all.

Comment: Good suggestion; I made the change and it works now. I think the NSFileManager was/is part of the problem. Since I'm still trying to learn most of this as I go it's sometimes unclear when I should be using NSURL, NSFileManager, etc., anyways thanks for your help.